# cocos2d-x v3 CallFunc as parameter/variable how to

Tags: c++, callback, cocos2d-x

I'm updating my V1 cocos2d-x app to V3 and I'm stuck on callbacks.

I can do call backs with lambdas like this, works fine -

```
auto mcb = CallFunc::create([this](){
    this->doCallback(kEVENT_MENU_IS_ONSCREEN);
});

hex->runAction(Sequence::create(somethingthattakestime, mcb, NULL) );
```

However, I want to pass a CallFunc variable into a function, store it in my object, then use/call it at some point in the future.

In a class I define -

```
CallFunc * callfunc;
```

Set with a simple -

```
item->callfunc = callfunc;
```

Within a function -

```
void LBMenuAddMenuItemName( CallFunc * callfunc );
```

I also declare the CallFunc variable as static so it hangs around -

```
static auto doSoloPlay = CallFunc::create([this](){
  CCLOG("doSoloPlay variable");
  this->menuSoloPlay();
});
```

Later when I wish to use this, I  do -

```
Sequence * seq = Sequence::create(callfunc,NULL);
somesprite->runAction(seq);
```

However, this ends badly with a SIGSEGV (GLThread).

Using typeid(callfunc).name() shows that callfunc is a CallFunc.  Using setTag(69) in declaration and then getTag() before SIGSEGV does not return a sensible value.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong and the correct method for delayed callbacks?

Thank you!

LB

Answer (score 0):

Tried many things then found this error goes away when I do a 'retain()' after the declaration -

```
doSoloPlay->retain();
```

This increases the reference count.

I don't quite know why I need this.  My guess is that cocos2d-x classes may do some clever garbage collection?

Answer (score 0):

If the function is called later as a callback, you need to retain the callback when you save it and release it at the right time.

The static declaration only save the address of your CCCallFunc but the class is destroyed before you wish to execute it.